# When is an Administrator not an Administrator? (Windows7)

Tags: windows-7, permissions, privileges

I'm running Windows7 Prof SP1.

My everyday, working account belongs to a domain, we'll call this account DOMAIN\Me.

I can also log in as the root user account, though I don't want to use this as my everyday account. But there are lots of things that the root account has privileges to do/run that DOMAIN\Me does not, even though:

1. DOMAIN\Me belongs to the group Administrators (although note I have to re-add it to this group on every reboot as windows "forgets").
2. DOMAIN\Me is the Owner and has Full Control of the entire hard drive.
3. UAC is turned fully off.

As an illustration, here's a screengrab of failing to install a program while logged in as DOMAIN\Me (and yes, I did "run as administrator") while at the same time I have the user account window open showing I am an Admin: [screengrab](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=d9dc755).

Many programs claim that I do not have Administrator Privileges and other things I am not allowed to do include edit windows firewall advanced settings or check a hard drive for errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine your statement 1 and the small text at the bottom of your Administrators window in your screen-shot ("changes are not effective until next login"). These two statements combined tell me that DOMAIN\Me **IS NEVER** considered by the system to be a member of Administrators group. This may explain your problems.

Comment: I don't think it does explain my problems. 
Note that Apply is greyed out in the Administrators window, indicating I am just opening the properties there, not changing them. Basically, how I add myself to Administrators is log in as root, add DOMAIN\Me to Administrators, then log off (or switch users). I can then log in as DOMAIN\Me and see I am in the Administrators group.

Comment: OK, I thought that somehow you were managing to add yourself to Administrator group while logged in as yourself (this would not be the only Winz oddity).

Comment: I am only using Win 7 (Enterprise) at work, so have limited ability to test my assumptions. Another difference that I noticed between your setup and mine here is that I have local user with same name as domain user (i.e. in your case it will be equivalent to having user local user "Me") who is also part of Administrators group. Give that a try and see if it changes anything.

Comment: No, that didn't do it. Thanks for trying though.